# What are the log Error Messages for ClientCheck and InvalidMemPool Error Types of Valgrind

Tags: linux, debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am running a script in which I am trying to get the all possible Error Valgrind messages in the log file. I have following error messages for corresponding Valgrind Error Types :

Error Types                   Error message in Log File

**1. InvalidFree**           I free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

**2. MismatchedFree**         Mismatched free() / delete / delete []

**3. InvalidRead**                Invalid read of size

**4. InvalidWrite**     Invalid write of size

**5. InvalidJump**      Jump to the invalid address

**6. Overlap**          Source and destination overlap in memcpy

**7. InvalidMemPool**
**8. UninitCondition**  Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value

**9. UninitValue**      Use of uninitialised value of size

**10. SyscallParam**    Syscall param execve(filename)

**11. ClientCheck**

**12. Leak_DefinitelyLost**     definitely lost in loss record

**13. Leak_IndirectlyLost**     Indirectly lost in loss record

**14. Leak_StillReachable**     still reachable in loss record

**15. Leak_PossiblyLos**t       Possibly Lost in loss record

I have no idea how to generate error for **ClientCheck** and **InvalidMemPool** Error types. Please let me know how to generate it or tell me what is the error message will be generated for these two types of Valgrind Error.

Answer (score 1):

ClientCheck errors are generated following memcheck.h client checks
inserted in  your code:client requests VALGRIND_CHECK_MEM_IS_ADDRESSABLE
or VALGRIND_CHECK_MEM_IS_DEFINED will generate such errors if the memory
is not addressable or not defined.

InvalidMemPool errors are generated when the 'POOL' related client requests
in valgrind.h are used incorrectly, typically referencing an incorrect
pool (for example, an already destroyed pool, or a not yet created pool)